# Is a SPA vulnerable to the BREACH https security exploit?

Tags: tls, web-application, http, single-page-app

I have a Single Page Application (SPA) that consists of static resources (HTML, JS, CSS, images fonts ...) that are served from an Apache web server and several API endpoints (serving JSON from a JBoss Backend, proxied through the same Apache that serves the static resources).

Client browsers have access to the SPA only via HTTPS.

Sensitive data is served exclusively from the API endpoints.

I would like to enable gzip compression for all the static resources.
gzip compression will not be enabled on the API endpoints.

Is enabling gzip compression on the static resources a security risk because of the [BREACH security exploit](http://breachattack.com/)?

I do not fully understand the BREACH attack:

- My static resources (which would be compressed) do not reflect any user data
- The API calls do reflect user data and can contain query parameters, but they are not compressed.

Is the above scenario vulnerable to the BREACH attack or not?

Comment: Is the SPA authenticated? BREACH affects session cookies as well as page data.

Comment: @Polynomial What is the criteria for the SPA "being authenticated" (forgive my ignorance). 
The SPA is loaded via static resources. 
Then the user authenticates with a dedicated API call, which returns a token.
The token is only used on subsequent API calls, not on reloading the static resources...

Comment: HTML compression can expose you to potential BREACH attacks, though as you say you do not reflect data back you are not technically vulnerable.  I recently fixed a breach vulnerability by using random tokens of random length, so that the length of data was not predictable.  This page helped me understand what the breach attack was - it can be a tricky one to get your head around.  http://www.securitylearn.net/2013/11/30/breach-attack-explained/

Comment: Does the user have to log into the website at any point? Either into a web page (I know you said it's static, but CGI auth is a thing), via basic auth, or NTLM auth, etc.

Comment: no, you're not compressing dynamic html, so you are immune.

Comment: @Polynomial Yes, the user has to log into the website. However the login-request is an API call that is not compressed. The API returns a 200 if the login is ok or a 403 if the login is not ok. We then store the login-token in JavaScript and set it on each subsequent API call.

Comment: @jbandi If no secret information is passed over the compressed channel, in requests or responses, body or headers, then you should not have any problems with BREACH.

Comment: @Polynomial Thanks, I would gladly accept your answer. But could you please elaborate the meaning of "compressed channel": If I have compressed static resources and uncompressed API calls, are they not using the same channel?

Comment: @jbandi Compressed static resources are fine as long as you're not sending things like session cookies as part of the requests for them - my advice would be to keep them on a secondary domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your link:

> To be vulnerable, a web application must:
>
> - Be served from a server that uses HTTP-level compression
> - Reflect    user-input in HTTP response bodies
> - Reflect a secret (such as a CSRF    token) in HTTP response bodies

However, if your resources are static and are the only items compressed then:

- **Be served from a server that uses HTTP-level compression**
- <strike>Reflect
  user-input in HTTP response bodies</strike>
- <strike>Reflect a secret (such as a CSRF
  token) in HTTP response bodies</strike>

For your non-compressed dynamic items:

- <strike>Be served from a server that uses HTTP-level compression</strike>
- **Reflect
  user-input in HTTP response bodies**
- **Reflect a secret (such as a CSRF
  token) in HTTP response bodies**

Key:

- **Applicable to your situation**
- <strike>Not applicable</strike>

As no one request satisfies all three requirements, you are not vulnerable to BREACH.

Comment: The thing that is not completely clear for me is: Must the three points be true for one request, or for the sum of all requests of the application?
i.e: Am I vulnerable if I serve static resources *with* HTTP-level compression and API-Calls/JSON-Data that reflect user-input *without* HTTP-level compression from the same server?

Comment: The three points must be true for a single request.